# Generate Ethereum addresses in HD Wallet using public key only (bitcoinj/web3j)

Tags: java, cryptography, ethereum, web3-java, bitcoinj

I trying to generate Ethereum addresses for the HD Wallet keys implemented with bitcoinj library, but I got confused:

```
DeterministicSeed seed = new DeterministicSeed("some seed code here", null, "", 1409478661L);
DeterministicKeyChain chain = DeterministicKeyChain.builder().seed(seed).build();
DeterministicKey addrKey = chain.getKeyByPath(HDUtils.parsePath("M/44H/60H/0H/0/0"), true);
System.out.println("address from pub=" + Keys.getAddress(Sign.publicKeyFromPrivate(addrKey.getPrivKey())));
```

this code prints a correct Ethereum address accordingly to https://iancoleman.io/bip39/. Everything is fine here.

But when I trying to avoid private key usage and generate non-hardened keys using public keys only I getting different results, i.e. the call returns another result:

```
System.out.println("address from pub=" + Keys.getAddress(addrKey.getPublicKeyAsHex()));
```

And it looks like the issue is in the "different public keys", i.e. result of the `Sign.publicKeyFromPrivate(addrKey.getPrivKey())` and `addrKey.getPublicKeyAsHex()` are different.
I'm not experienced with cryptography, thus it may be a silly question... but I would appreciate any advice here.

Answer (score 10):

Like Bitcoin, [Ethereum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethereum) uses *secp256k1*. [Ethereum addresses](https://github.com/ethereumbook/ethereumbook/blob/develop/04keys-addresses.asciidoc?ref=hackernoon.com#ethereum-addresses) are derived as follows:

- Step 1: The 32 bytes x and y coordinate of the public key are concatenated to 64 bytes (where both the x and y coordinate are padded with leading 0x00 values if necessary).
- Step 2: From this the *Keccak-256* hash is generated.
- Step 3: The last 20 bytes are used as the Ethereum address.

For the examples used here, the key is generated with:

```java
String mnemonic = "elevator dinosaur switch you armor vote black syrup fork onion nurse illegal trim rocket combine";
DeterministicSeed seed = new DeterministicSeed(mnemonic, null, "", 1409478661L);
DeterministicKeyChain chain = DeterministicKeyChain.builder().seed(seed).build();
DeterministicKey addrKey = chain.getKeyByPath(HDUtils.parsePath("M/44H/60H/0H/0/0"), true);
```

This corresponds to the following public key and Ethereum address:

```
      X: a35bf0fdf5df296cc3600422c3c8af480edb766ff6231521a517eb822dff52cd
      Y: 5440f87f5689c2929542e75e739ff30cd1e8cb0ef0beb77380d02cd7904978ca
Address: 23ad59cc6afff2e508772f69d22b19ffebf579e7
```

as can also be verified with the website https://iancoleman.io/bip39/.

---

**Step 1:**

In the posted question, the expressions [`Sign.publicKeyFromPrivate()`](https://github.com/web3j/web3j/blob/5934a730c498d25c6910903c826b3f50559e58fb/crypto/src/main/java/org/web3j/crypto/Sign.java#L272) and [`addrKey.getPublicKeyAsHex()`](https://github.com/bitcoinj/bitcoinj/blob/1bcea2a59c99fe53f2eeab788eef1fd396f4b566/core/src/main/java/org/bitcoinj/core/ECKey.java#L1259) provide different results. Both functions return the public key in different types. While `Sign.publicKeyFromPrivate()` uses a `BigInteger`, `addrKey.getPublicKeyAsHex()` provides a hex string. For a direct comparison, `BigInteger` can be converted to a hex string with `toString(16)`. When the results of both expressions are displayed with:

```java
System.out.println(Sign.publicKeyFromPrivate(addrKey.getPrivKey()).toString(16));
System.out.println(addrKey.getPublicKeyAsHex());
```

the following result is obtained:

```
a35bf0fdf5df296cc3600422c3c8af480edb766ff6231521a517eb822dff52cd5440f87f5689c2929542e75e739ff30cd1e8cb0ef0beb77380d02cd7904978ca
02a35bf0fdf5df296cc3600422c3c8af480edb766ff6231521a517eb822dff52cd
```

The output of `Sign.publicKeyFromPrivate()` has a length of 64 bytes and corresponds to the concatenated x and y coordinate as defined in step 1. Therefore, the address generated with this is a valid Ethereum address, as also described in the posted question.

The output of `addrKey.getPublicKeyAsHex()`, on the other hand, corresponds to the x coordinate prefixed with a 0x02 value. This is the [*compressed*](https://davidederosa.com/basic-blockchain-programming/elliptic-curve-keys/) format of the public key. The leading byte has either the value 0x02 if the y value is even (as in this example), or the value 0x03. Since the compressed format does not contain the y coordinate, this cannot be used to *directly* infer the Ethereum address, or if it is done anyway, it will result in a wrong address (indirectly, of course, it would be possible since the y coordinate can be derived from a compressed public key).

---

The [*uncompressed*](https://davidederosa.com/basic-blockchain-programming/elliptic-curve-keys/) format of the public key can be obtained, e.g. with [`addrKey.decompress()`](https://github.com/bitcoinj/bitcoinj/blob/1bcea2a59c99fe53f2eeab788eef1fd396f4b566/core/src/main/java/org/bitcoinj/core/ECKey.java#L306):

```java
System.out.println(addrKey.decompress().getPublicKeyAsHex());
```

which gives this result:

```
04a35bf0fdf5df296cc3600422c3c8af480edb766ff6231521a517eb822dff52cd5440f87f5689c2929542e75e739ff30cd1e8cb0ef0beb77380d02cd7904978ca
```

The uncompressed format consists of a leading marker byte with the value 0x04 followed by the x and y coordinates. So if the leading marker byte is removed, just the data according to step 1 is obtained, which is needed for the derivation of the Ethereum address:

```java
System.out.println(addrKey.decompress().getPublicKeyAsHex().substring(2));
```

which results in:

```
a35bf0fdf5df296cc3600422c3c8af480edb766ff6231521a517eb822dff52cd5440f87f5689c2929542e75e739ff30cd1e8cb0ef0beb77380d02cd7904978ca
```

---

**Steps 2 and 3:**

Steps 2 and 3 are performed by [`Keys.getAddress()`](https://github.com/web3j/web3j/blob/5934a730c498d25c6910903c826b3f50559e58fb/crypto/src/main/java/org/web3j/crypto/Keys.java#L101). This allows the Ethereum address to be obtained using the uncompressed public key as follows:

```java
System.out.println(Keys.getAddress(addrKey.decompress().getPublicKeyAsHex().substring(2)));
System.out.println(Keys.getAddress(Sign.publicKeyFromPrivate(addrKey.getPrivKey())));       // For comparison
```

which gives the Ethereum address:

```
23ad59cc6afff2e508772f69d22b19ffebf579e7
23ad59cc6afff2e508772f69d22b19ffebf579e7
```

---

**Overloads of `Keys.getAddress()`:**

`Keys.getAddress()` provides various overloads for the data types `BigInteger`, hex string and `byte[]`. If the uncompressed key is given as `byte[]`, e.g. with [`addrKey.getPubKeyPoint().getEncoded(false)`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk15on/latest/org/bouncycastle/math/ec/ECPoint.html#getEncoded-boolean-), the `byte[]` can be used directly after removing the marker byte. Alternatively, the `byte[]` can be converted to a `BigInteger` with the marker byte removed:

```java
byte[] uncompressed = addrKey.getPubKeyPoint().getEncoded(false);
System.out.println(bytesToHex(Keys.getAddress(Arrays.copyOfRange(uncompressed, 1, uncompressed.length))).toLowerCase());  // bytesToHex() from https://stackoverflow.com/a/9855338
System.out.println(Keys.getAddress(new BigInteger(1, uncompressed, 1, uncompressed.length - 1)));
System.out.println(Keys.getAddress(Sign.publicKeyFromPrivate(addrKey.getPrivKey())));                                     // For comparison
```

which as expected returns the same Ethereum address:

```
23ad59cc6afff2e508772f69d22b19ffebf579e7
23ad59cc6afff2e508772f69d22b19ffebf579e7
23ad59cc6afff2e508772f69d22b19ffebf579e7
```

One thing to note here is that [`Keys.getAddress(byte[]`)](https://github.com/web3j/web3j/blob/5934a730c498d25c6910903c826b3f50559e58fb/crypto/src/main/java/org/web3j/crypto/Keys.java#L113) does not pad the passed `byte[]`, while the overloads for `BigInteger` or hex strings *implicitly* pad. This can be relevant e.g. when converting a `BigInteger` (e.g. provided by `Sign.publicKeyFromPrivate(addrKey.getPrivKey())`) to a `byte[]`, since the result can also have less than 64 bytes (which would lead to different *Keccak-256* hashes). If `Keys.getAddress(byte[])` is used in this case, it must be `explicitly` padded with leading 0x00 values up to a length of 64 bytes.

Comment: Thanks, this is a great answer!

Comment: great thanks, my bro